# Template no renderiza la informacion solicitada de filtro django

Tags: html, django, class, filtro

no puedo renderizar los resultados del filtro de un 'producto' en mi template, los otros filtros funcionan perfectamente mostrando la informacion solicitada. El proyecto contiene una carpeta apps donde se encuentran las carpetas 'producto' conteniendo los codigos detallados a continuacion y otra carpeta 'administracion' donde se encuentra el modelo de 'proveedor'.

Adjunto codigos del modelo, vistas, urls y template:
este es mi codigo del archivo modelo:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields import DateTimeField
from apps.administracion.models import Proveedor
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from decimal import Decimal
import locale

class Producto(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   proveedor = models.ForeignKey(Proveedor, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=False, null=False)
   nombre = models.CharField(verbose_name='Descripcion del Producto', max_length=100, 
blank=False, null=False)
   modelo = models.ForeignKey('Modelo', on_delete=models.PROTECT,blank=False, null=False)
   subfamilia = models.ForeignKey('Subfamilia', on_delete=models.PROTECT,blank=False, null=False)

class Meta:
   verbose_name = 'Producto'
   verbose_name_plural = 'Productos'

def __str__(self):
   subfamilia = self.subfamilia
   modelo = self.modelo
   return subfamilia.familia.familia + ' - ' + subfamilia.subfamilia + ' - ' + 
modelo.marca.marca + ' - ' + modelo.modelo + ' - ' + self.nombre + ' - ' + self.color.color + 
" ("+ self.proveedor.razonSocial +")"
```

codigo contenido en archivo de vistas:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, TemplateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.forms import formset_factory
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from .models import *
from .forms import ProductoForm, MarcaModeloForm, FamiliaSubfamiliaForm, CostoForm, 
EstudioMercadoForm, EstudioMercadoDetalleForm

from .mixins import GetEstudioMercadoMixin
from .filters import CostoFilter, ProductoFilter

class ListarProducto(ListView):
    model = Producto
    template_name = LISTAR_PRODUCTO_FILE
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    productos_filter = ProductoFilter(request.GET, queryset= Producto.objects.all())
    return render(request, LISTAR_PRODUCTO_FILE, {'filter': productos_filter})
```

detallo rutas en archivo urls:

```
 from django.urls import path
 from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
 from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
   path('listarProducto/', login_required(ListarProducto.as_view()), name ='listarProducto'),]
```

finalmente parte del template donde quiero que renderice el filtro:

```
 {% extends 'index.html' %}

 <div id="filtros-details" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data 
    parent="#filtros">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form method="GET">   
                <div class="form-group d-flex ">
                    <div class="form-group-filters mr-2 
                    {% if filter.form.subfamilia__familia.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
                        <label class="control-label font-weight-bold" 
                        for="{{filter.form.subfamilia__familia.auto_id }}">
                        {{ filter.form.subfamilia__familia.label }}:</label>
                          <div> {{ filter.form.subfamilia__familia }}</div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group-filters mr-2
                    {% if filter.form.modelo__marca.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
                        <label class="control-label font-weight-bold"
                        for="{{filter.form.modelo__marca.auto_id }}"> 
                        {{ filter.form.modelo__marca.label }}: </label>
                          <div> {{ filter.form.modelo__marca }}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group-filters mr-2
                    {% if filter.form.nombre.errors %}has- error{% endif %}">
                        <label class="control-label font-weight-bold" 
                        for="{{ filter.form.nombre.auto_id }}"> 
                        {{ filter.form.nombre.label }}: </label>
                          <div> {{ filter.form.nombre }}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Filtrar</button>
                <a class="btn btn-secondary" 
                href="{% url 'producto:listarProducto' %}">Limpiar</a>             
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer"></div>
 <div class="table-stats order-table ov-h">
        {% if filter.qs %}
        <table id="tabla_productos" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>FAMILIA | SUBFAMILIA</th>
                    <th>MARCA | MODELO</th>
                    <th>DESCRIPCION</th>
                    <th>PROVEEDOR</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% if filter.qs %}
                    {% for producto in filter.qs %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ producto.id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ producto.subfamilia.familia.familia }} | 
                                {{ producto.subfamilia.subfamilia }}</td>
                            <td>{{ producto.modelo.marca.marca }} | 
                                {{ producto.modelo.model }}</td>
                            <td>{{ producto.nombre }}</td>
                            <td>{{ producto.proveedor.razonSocial }}</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% else %}
                    <tr><td class="text-left">No existen Productos registrados.</td></tr>
                {% endif %} 
            </tbody>
        </table>
        {% else %}
           <h3> No existen productos registrados</h3>
        {% endif %}
 </div>
```

[image: resultado del filtro que no anda]